# Cannot allocate memory error

Tags: error, memory

I'm running a container based on the official solana image.
Dockerfile:

```
ARG SOLANA_VERSION=v1.11.3
FROM solanalabs/solana:${SOLANA_VERSION}
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $VALIDATOR_IDENTITY
set -e
if [[ -e $VALIDATOR_IDENTITY ]]; then
  echo "Use existing validator keypair"
else
  solana-keygen new --no-passphrase -so "$VALIDATOR_IDENTITY"
fi
exec solana-validator "$@"
```

I'm starting a docker-compose file with the following args:

```
version: '3'
services:
  solana:
    image: ${REGISTRY_URL}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${SOLANA_IMAGE_TAG}
    container_name: solana
    command: 
      --ledger /solana/ledger
      --identity /solana/data/validator-identity.json 
      --expected-genesis-hash 4uhcVJyU9pJkvQyS88uRDiswHXSCkY3zQawwpjk2NsNY
      --rpc-port 8899 
      --gossip-host $BLOCKCHAIN_HOST_EXTERNAL
      --gossip-port 8801
      --dynamic-port-range 8802-8815
      --full-rpc-api 
      --no-voting 
      --enable-rpc-transaction-history 
      --limit-ledger-size 
      --known-validator 5D1fNXzvv5NjV1ysLjirC4WY92RNsVH18vjmcszZd8on 
      --known-validator dDzy5SR3AXdYWVqbDEkVFdvSPCtS9ihF5kJkHCtXoFs 
      --known-validator Ft5fbkqNa76vnsjYNwjDZUXoTWpP7VYm3mtsaQckQADN 
      --known-validator eoKpUABi59aT4rR9HGS3LcMecfut9x7zJyodWWP43YQ 
      --known-validator 9QxCLckBiJc783jnMvXZubK4wH86Eqqvashtrwvcsgkv 
      --entrypoint entrypoint.testnet.solana.com:8001 
      --entrypoint entrypoint2.testnet.solana.com:8001 
      --entrypoint entrypoint3.testnet.solana.com:8001  
      --only-known-rpc 
      --log - 
      --no-os-network-limits-test 
      --init-complete-file /solana/data/init-completed 
      --no-port-check
    ports:
      - 8899:8899
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 1000000
        hard: 1000000
```

After starting a container and after getting some init messages, I'm getting an error:

```
solana          | [2022-07-21T12:50:28.414766618Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: cpu-stats cpu_num=28i cpu0_freq_mhz=3230i average_load_one_minute=3.3 average_load_five_minutes=2.53 average_load_fifteen_minutes=2.14 total_num_threads=2000i
solana          | [2022-07-21T12:50:28.914924215Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: memory-stats total=134721150976i swap_total=9663668224i free_percent=3.5714674445270678 used_bytes=58626637824i avail_percent=56.48297435163385 buffers_percent=0.7306305274777168 cached_percent=50.49884609441892 swap_free_percent=1.8690760880161608
solana          | thread 'main' panicked at 'Load from snapshot failed: Serialize(Io(Os { code: 12, kind: OutOfMemory, message: "Cannot allocate memory" }))', ledger/src/bank_forks_utils.rs:212:10
solana          | stack backtrace:
solana          |    0: rust_begin_unwind
solana          |              at ./rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/std/src/panicking.rs:584:5
solana          |    1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
solana          |              at ./rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/core/src/panicking.rs:143:14
solana          |    2: core::result::unwrap_failed
solana          |              at ./rustc/7737e0b5c4103216d6fd8cf941b7ab9bdbaace7c/library/core/src/result.rs:1749:5
solana          |    3: solana_ledger::bank_forks_utils::load_bank_forks
solana          |    4: solana_core::validator::load_blockstore
solana          |    5: solana_core::validator::Validator::new
solana          |    6: solana_validator::main
solana          | note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
solana          | [2022-07-21T12:50:29.232095785Z ERROR solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: panic program="validator" thread="main" one=1i message="panicked at 'Load from snapshot failed: Serialize(Io(Os { code: 12, kind: OutOfMemory, message: \"Cannot allocate memory\" }))', ledger/src/bank_forks_utils.rs:212:10" location="ledger/src/bank_forks_utils.rs:212:10" version="\"1.11.3 (src:1db136a8; feat:3270869161)\""
```

A question is how to set limit to the solana daemon? I'm trying to run a test node on a shared host with other blockchains.

Comment: What are the `docker stats` before the container dies? What happens if you try to reserve more memory in Docker compose by setting your service's `deploy.resources.reservations.memory` attribute?

Comment: @sohrab it reaches 100% and dies. I've tried to increase reservations memory, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

For starters running a validator with Docker is unsupported.  The image you're using is purely for use in Solana Labs CI jobs and is not intended for production.

You need to perform the [system tuning steps](https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#manual) on both the host and guest